# progressbar not sync to countdown

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a simple countdown with a progress bar that increases while its counting down and displaying a random number and reset again after 10 seconds.
the first attempt is working but on the second its not syncing anymore. if I put this line `this.stop()` back, it can be sync. my problem is there will be another problem. it will generate extra array.

Hope you help me.

thanks.

```js
let time = 10;
let progress = 0; let counter = 0
var clock = $('.my-clock').FlipClock(time, {
  countdown: true,
  count: 1,
  callbacks: {
    stop: function() {
      
      setTimeout(function(){
        clock.setTime(time); // proceeding time
        clock.start();
      },10000);
        
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            
            
            var arrResult = [];

            setTimeout(function(){
            var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1;    
            arrResult.push(r);
              
              
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.numResult div:nth-child('+ (i+1) +')').html(arrResult[i]);
                },200);
              
              if(arrResult.length === 5){
                $('.results ul').append('<li>'+ arrResult +'</li>');
              }
                
            
        },500 * i);
            
        }
    },
    interval: function() {
      counter && (progress+=100/time);
      counter ++;
      $('.progressBar .progress').width(progress+ '%');
      if(progress >= 100) {
        progress = 0; counter = 0;
        
        // this.stop()
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.my-clock {
  text-align:center;
  width:auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
.center {
  text-align:center;
  
}
.progressBar{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #222;
}
.progress{
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.numResult div{
  display: inline-block;
}
.results{
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.results ul{
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.js"></script>
<div class="center">
  <div class="my-clock"></div>
  <div class="progressBar">
    <div class="progress"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="numResult">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="results">
    <ul>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got mistyfied on that one for a while too.
Timing issues often are subtile.

The thing is... That the `interval` callback fires **at the beginning** of the number flip animation (which has a 1 second delay).

So to the human eye, the number shown when the very first callback fires is 10... And is just starts flipping to 09. At this moment, you do not want to upgrade the progressbar, since there is still 10 seconds left (or say 9.99 seconds). That is why you did `counter && (progress+=100/time);` which is the equivalent of `if(counter){progress+=100/time;}`.

That creates an "iteration skip" on `progress`... And it is offseting by one each time the `counter` equals 0. See here:

```js
console.clear();

let time = 10;
let progress = 0; let counter = 0
var clock = $('.my-clock').FlipClock(time, {
  countdown: true,
  count: 1,
  callbacks: {
    stop: function() {

      setTimeout(function(){
        clock.setTime(time); // proceeding time
        clock.start();
      },10000);

      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        var arrResult = [];

        setTimeout(function(){
          var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1;    
          arrResult.push(r);

          setTimeout(function(){
            $('.numResult div:nth-child('+ (i+1) +')').html(arrResult[i]);
          },200);

          if(arrResult.length === 5){
            $('.results ul').append('<li>'+ arrResult +'</li>');
          }

        },500 * i);
      }
    },
    interval: function() {

      // Check for that progress being consoled to zero TWICE on load.
      console.log("progress: "+progress);
      
      counter && (progress+=100/time);
      counter ++;

      $('.progressBar .progress').width(progress+ '%');
      
      if(progress == 100) {
        progress = 0; counter = 0;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.my-clock {
  text-align:center;
  width:auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
.center {
  text-align:center;

}
.progressBar{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #222;
}
.progress{
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.numResult div{
  display: inline-block;
}
.results{
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.results ul{
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.js"></script>
<div class="center">
  <div class="my-clock"></div>
  <div class="progressBar">
    <div class="progress"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="numResult">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="results">
    <ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

So having skipped the **very first** iteration (the one on page load), your callback "timing" is now aligned with the end of the flip animation (to the human eye). That is correct and you have to not "skip" an iteration again.

So when the `progress` will equal 100, reset the `progress` to 0... But reset the `counter` to 1! So you won't be skipping again. See here:

```js
console.clear();

let time = 10;
let progress = 0; let counter = 0
var clock = $('.my-clock').FlipClock(time, {
  countdown: true,
  count: 1,
  callbacks: {
    stop: function() {

      setTimeout(function(){
        clock.setTime(time); // proceeding time
        clock.start();
      },10000);

      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        var arrResult = [];

        setTimeout(function(){
          var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1;    
          arrResult.push(r);

          setTimeout(function(){
            $('.numResult div:nth-child('+ (i+1) +')').html(arrResult[i]);
          },200);

          if(arrResult.length === 5){
            $('.results ul').append('<li>'+ arrResult +'</li>');
          }

        },500 * i);
      }
    },
    interval: function() {

      // Check for that progress being consoled to zero TWICE on load.
      console.log("progress: "+progress);
      
      counter && (progress+=100/time);
      counter ++;

      $('.progressBar .progress').width(progress+ '%');
      
      if(progress == 100) {
        progress = 0; counter = 1;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.my-clock {
  text-align:center;
  width:auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
.center {
  text-align:center;

}
.progressBar{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #222;
}
.progress{
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.numResult div{
  display: inline-block;
}
.results{
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.results ul{
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.js"></script>
<div class="center">
  <div class="my-clock"></div>
  <div class="progressBar">
    <div class="progress"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="numResult">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="results">
    <ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

So now, the progressbar and the Flipclock stays aligned. Good. But you certainly noticed that the progress bar never comes back to 0. And the progressbar updates when the flipping **begins**!

That is because the progressbar update doesn't have an animation delay like Flipclock. So why not `animate()` the width instead of using `.width()` ?

```
$('.progressBar .progress').animate({"width":progress+ '%'},1000,"linear");
```

See here:

```js
console.clear();

let time = 10;
let progress = 0; let counter = 0
var clock = $('.my-clock').FlipClock(time, {
  countdown: true,
  count: 1,
  callbacks: {
    stop: function() {

      setTimeout(function(){
        clock.setTime(time); // proceeding time
        clock.start();
      },10000);

      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        var arrResult = [];

        setTimeout(function(){
          var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1;    
          arrResult.push(r);

          setTimeout(function(){
            $('.numResult div:nth-child('+ (i+1) +')').html(arrResult[i]);
          },200);

          if(arrResult.length === 5){
            $('.results ul').append('<li>'+ arrResult +'</li>');
          }

        },500 * i);
      }
    },
    interval: function() {
      
      if(progress == 0){
        $('.progressBar .progress').width("0%");
      }
      
      counter && (progress+=100/time);
      counter ++;

      $('.progressBar .progress').animate({"width":progress+ '%'},1000,"linear");
      
      if(progress == 100) {
        progress = 0; counter = 1;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.my-clock {
  text-align:center;
  width:auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
.center {
  text-align:center;

}
.progressBar{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #222;
}
.progress{
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.numResult div{
  display: inline-block;
}
.results{
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.results ul{
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.js"></script>
<div class="center">
  <div class="my-clock"></div>
  <div class="progressBar">
    <div class="progress"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="numResult">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="results">
    <ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `.width()` still is usefull when `progress` is 0 because you don't want to see an animation from 100 to 10... But from 0 to 10. That's why the added condition.

```
if(progress == 0){
  $('.progressBar .progress').width("0%");
}
```

**The last snippet** would be your solution... ;)

I left all the console logs I used to investigate the issue in this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/GBdayx?editors=1011).

Comment: Look at the 2 first snippets in full page mode, since there are console logs... ;)